# How many ways to form the “promotion set” from the menu

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a restaurant, you can order its “promotion set” that is $3$ soups, $3$ appetizers, and $5$ dinners. If the menu  just contains $6$ soups, $8$ appetizers, and $17$ dinners(all the soups, appetizers, dinners are different flavors).You may choose any dishes in the menu to form the “promotion set”.(Let say I can choose any $3$ of the soups from the $6$ soups given in the menu.) If I wanted to buy one ”promotion set” in the restaurant, how many different sets can I form from the menu?

I did $6C3* 8C3 * 17C5$ and I get $6$,$930$,$560$ but my professor got
$470$,$288$ in the answer key. I can't figure out how to do it correctly. Could someone help me to check my solution, please?

Comment: The other answer seems to be the result of C(17,5) * (C(6,3) + C(8,3)). That would be the answer if an order must contain either 3 soups (and 5 dinners) or 3 appetizers (and 5 dinners), but that is not what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your wording is correct, then your solution sounds good. Maybe, try to check the question if you miss something.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I emailed my professor and my answer was correct. I guess he just messed up on his answer